# Datatable missing some rows when open in modal

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, datatable

In html I have a table defined inside a modal that opens when I click a button:

```
<button type="button" id="myBtn" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="createTable()">Open modal</button> 

<div class="modal" id="myModal">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title">myTable</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-fixed"  style="width:100%" id="myTable">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>ID</th>
              <th>Name</th>
              <th>Date</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="myTableBody"> </tbody>
          </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to destroy and create the table each time I click the button, so I've defined this Javascript function to do that:

```
function createTable()
{
  data = [{ID:'1', Name:'Name1', Date:'2022-04-27'}, {ID:'2', Name:'Name2', Date:'2022-04-27'}, {ID:'3', Name:'Name3', Date:'2022-04-27'}, {ID:'4', Name:'Name4', Date:'2022-04-27'} ]; // example of data

  $("#myTable").find('tbody').empty(); // reset table
  for (var i=0; i<data.length; i++) // fill rows
  {
    var row = `<tr>
      <th scope="row"> ${data[i].ID}</th>
      <td>${data[i].Name}</td>
      <td>${data[i].Date}</td>
    </tr>`
    $("#myTable").find('tbody').append(row);
  }
  $("#myModal").modal("show"); // open modal
  $('#myTable').DataTable({
    scrollY: '400px',
    scrollCollapse: true,
    destroy: true 
  })     
}
```

The problem is that, when I click the button, the modal opens but the table does not always contains all the data: sometimes the first rows (of  `data`) are missing. If I refresh the page and then open the modal, all the rows are present.

`data` has size > 1000 and is taken from a DB, but in the code I only put an example of it. Here is the code https://jsfiddle.net/326w480u/

Any idea of the cause of this behavior?

**EDIT1:**

briefly, the problem is that `Datatable` is updated only when I refresh the page, not when I close and open the modal

**EDIT2:**

I solved populating the `Datatable` when I define it, and not by means of the for loop:

```
  $('#myTable').DataTable({
    scrollY: '400px',
    data: data,
    columns: [{data:'ID'},{data:'Name'},{data:'Date'}],
    scrollCollapse: true,
    destroy: true 
  })
```

Comment: your example always shows 4 entries - so, it's not really demonstrating the issue at all - `data has size > 1000 and is taken from a DB` you're probably *doing something wrong™* in the code you omitted from the question

Comment: You're right, but I can't fully replicate my example here. In fact, I tried to be as clear as possible to specify my problem

Comment: the problem is likely to be in the code you have removed

Comment: I'm quite sure that there are not problems in the code that I've not posted. I'm sure that ```data``` passed to ```createTable()``` contains all the rows that have to fill the ```Datatable```, but I don't know why it is not updated

Comment: Yeah I agree with the above, I made a fork of your fiddle with 2000 data rows and it seems to be working? https://jsfiddle.net/treckstar/nc3jwxqv/

Comment: Thanks, it's true. But in the fiddle the code is run after data is defined, while in my case the content of data changes continuously

Comment: you're probably doing something wrong with `data` - again, that's the part you have not shown

Comment: Does your "EDIT2" mean you solved the overall issue?

Comment: Exactly, I solved in this way